# Ramification of prime ideal in Kummer extension

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification, kummer-theory

Let $\mu \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ lie above the rational prime $p$, and let the prime ideal $\mathscr{P}\subset \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ have ramification index $a$ over $\mu$.

Why is it then true that $\mathscr{P}$ has ramification index $\frac{n}{(a,n)}$ over $p$?

In "Reciprocity Laws: from Euler to Eisenstein'', it's stated that this is from the decomposition law in Kummer extensions (as $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n, \mu^{1/n})/\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is Kummer) but I cannot find any reference about this. Does anyone know of one?

I assume it's irrelevant, but just in case: $\mu$ here is the $n$th power of a Gauss sum of a residue character.

Comment: What does it mean for an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ to lie above $p$? Do you mean it's an element of $p\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$?

Then what does it mean for $\mathcal{P}$ to have ramification index $a$ over an element $\mu$? What if $(\mu)$ isn't prime? Do you mean that all the ramification indices over the prime ideals dividing $(\mu)$ are the same and are equal to $a$?

Comment: And what is $m$? is $m = \mu$? If $m$ is not an integer, what does $(a,m)$ mean?

Comment: @oxeimon The latter was a typo, and $\mathscr{P}$ has ramification index $a$ over element $r \in \mathbb{Z}(\zeta_n)$ if it has exponent $a$ in the prime ideal factorisation of $(r)$.

Comment: @Alyosha, in the first line shouldn't $\mathscr P$ lie in the integers of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n,\sqrt[n]{\mu})$, not $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$?

Answer (score 2):

This follows from basic properties of Kummer extensions and the Eisenstein polynomial of your prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.

You can find it for example in [Koch's book on Algebraic Number Theory](https://books.google.es/books?id=wt1sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=ramification+in+kummer+extensions&source=bl&ots=stmc51trmz&sig=Y2-lz2O5Uol2-o-ki5WFFCsk-ZU&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0CHkQ6AEwCWoVChMI4r_-isG4yAIVhboaCh13bwF4#v=onepage&q=ramification%20in%20kummer%20extensions&f=false).

If you still have problems with it, it might make for a good math.stackexchange question.